# Post installation styles are missing on the sitecore login and content editor pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, content-editor

I did an installation of sitecore on one of a dev server and copied over the site root folder to a bunch of dev machines. This process worked fine on 6 of the 7 machines and we can see the sitecore login and content editor pages fine and browse to the site through IIS.
On one of the machines on browsing to site / sitecore in the browser we are not seeing any of the styles come through. After logging in same is the case with the content editor.

I did a comparison of the web config on the server and one of the dev machines with the machine which has the issue and cannot spot any differences. Also did a comparison of IIS settings for the site on with the server IIS settings and couldn't find any difference.

Anyone has any suggestions on what could be wrong or what can be done next to troubleshoot the issue?

Using sitecore 6.5 on windows 7 as the dev machine.

FIXED: Went to IIS->sites->SiteName. On the right under IIS, Authentication. Right click Anonymous Authentication, make sure it is enabled and change the anonymous user identity to Application pool identity. Recycle app pool. Should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the "Static Content" feature isn't enabled for IIS. You can check it in the "Turn Windows features on or off", "Internet Information Services", "Worlds Wide Web Services", "Common HTTP Features".

If the feature is installed, check the issue with Fiddler - look at the status code and content that all .css requests return.

Comment: Hi Alen, Thanks for the reply. I looked into the http features static content box - it was already checked. Upon using Fiddler I see there is a 401 on the css and js.

I looked into the security settings for the app pool.
The appPool for the site is running under the network service user and the network service user has full control to the entire site directory.

Answer (score 0):

The styles weren't loading for our Admin login page.
The solution was to enable SSL in IIS.